# How can I fix my routing errors for the code below?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a hard time fixing my routing paths. For example, I am trying to create a path that goes to a create new lesson page.

```
<li><%= link_to "new lesson", course_lesson_path %></li>
```

I get the error saying

> ```
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"lessons"}, missing required keys: [:course_id, :id]
> ```

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                      devise/sessions#destroy
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                 devise/passwords#edit
           user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#update
                         POST   /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                        devise/registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                          devise/registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#destroy
                         POST   /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#create
                    root GET    /                                              devise/registrations#new
          course_lessons GET    /courses/:course_id/lessons(.:format)          lessons#index
                         POST   /courses/:course_id/lessons(.:format)          lessons#create
       new_course_lesson GET    /courses/:course_id/lessons/new(.:format)      lessons#new
      edit_course_lesson GET    /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id/edit(.:format) lessons#edit
           course_lesson GET    /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id(.:format)      lessons#show
                         PATCH  /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id(.:format)      lessons#update
                         PUT    /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id(.:format)      lessons#update
                         DELETE /courses/:course_id/lessons/:id(.:format)      lessons#destroy
                 courses GET    /courses(.:format)                             courses#index
                         POST   /courses(.:format)                             courses#create
              new_course GET    /courses/new(.:format)                         courses#new
             edit_course GET    /courses/:id/edit(.:format)                    courses#edit
                  course GET    /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#show
                         PATCH  /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#update
                         PUT    /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#update
                         DELETE /courses/:id(.:format)                         courses#destroy
```

I am thinking the way I created my models weren't good as I had a course model and a lesson model and I used course:reference in my lesson model attribute and that kind of messed things up.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, if you want to create a link which redirects to the new `/courses/:course_id/lessons/new` path, you need to use the `new_course_lesson_path` passing the needed `course_id`, like:

```
<li><%= link_to "new lesson", new_course_lesson_path(id: 1) %></li> <!-- 1 as example -->
```

The reason you see the `missing required keys: [:course_id, :id]` error is because the `course_lesson_path` has been defined to receive two values within the params:

```
/courses/:course_id/lessons/:id # :course_id and :id
```

In that case it'd be something like:

```
<li><%= link_to "new lesson", course_lesson_path(course_id: 1, id: 1) %></li> <!-- 1 and 1 as example -->
```

Comment: `new_course_lesson_path` method needs to be called with `:course_id`, not `:id` if you supply the arguments as a Hash. Alternatively call it like @sbulat with only the value, although I like your way for readability.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked but I prefer not to hard code the course id. If I add a new course, that means how would I be able to create a lesson that belongs to that course?

Comment: Yes, those values were only as an example. If you're in a route which has access to any course, then you already have the id, from there you have the course  for whom you're going to create a lesson.

Answer (score 1):

`course_lesson_path` as you used it points to show action for lesson (within course) i.e. it needs `course_id` (the id of the parent) and lesson `id`.

And you want to point to new lesson path, so you need to use `new_course_lesson_path` with specified id of the course e.g.:
`<li><%= link_to "new lesson", new_course_lesson_path(@course_id) %></li>`
@course_id being id of course within you want to create that lesson.

Answer (score 1):

```
lessons_controller.rb
# need to load course from controller
def new 
  @course = Course.find(:course_id)
end

In your new.erb.html

<li><%= link_to "new lesson", course_lesson_path(@course) %></li>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.